# Access Spark/Cassandra from C# (or ODBC)

Tags: c#, sql, cassandra, apache-spark

I work on a proprietary piece of software written in C# with SQLServer for storage. I evaluate possibilities of a full/partial replacement of storage with NoSQL Database (mainly for time series analytics) and was considering using Cassandra. I successfully connect and use Cassandra using provided C# driver but for analytics, I understand an efficient way would be using Spark. Therefore, I try to setup a config where I can run basic SQL queries (group by mainly) against a Spark/Cassandra cluster using Spark SQL and ODBC Driver (ODBC driver for Spark exists). Without any success for now.

Is anyone already used such a config ? Is it possible ? Else, could you point me to the right direction ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code you've written and the errors that you are getting.

Comment: I have no code written for now hence no errors. This is a config problem. I can't even manage to find a way to connect to a Spark/Cassandra cluster using the ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you but it might be worth knowing that a C# language binding for Apache Spark is now available through Mobius.

See below for more info: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius 
https://spark-summit.org/2016/events/mobius-c-language-binding-for-spark/

Comment: I'm not working on this anymore but c# binding is certainly a good option !